# Representing particle motion in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I've never used `numpy` to represent more than `images` or `volumetric data` I would run operations on them. Anyhow is numpy good for storing a table or is this more suited to accomplish on pandas?

I basically need to store particles to represent particle motion and I'm not sure how I would define a shape so i can run for example `linalg.svd` on the Matrix and update the last field `Determinant`

```
Position (Vector3 or 3 floats)
Velocity (Vector3 or 3 floats)
Matrix (Matrix or 9 floats)
Determinant (1 float)
```

I imagined that I would create a shape `(16, 1000)` to hold 1000 particles but how would I reshape the `matrix` of 9 floats so I can pass it to `linalg.svd`

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy handles this case quite well, using [structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.rec.html).
For your particular case, you can create an array as follows (Assuming you want Matrix to be 3x3 for use with the SVD).
*edit*: It should be `np.zeros` to create the array, then you can copy data over row by row or field by field.

```
d = dtype([('pos', float, 3), ('v', float, 3), ('Matrix', float, (3, 3)), ('det', float)])
arr = np.zeros(1000, dtype=d).view(np.recarray)
```

You don't have to take a view as a `recarray`, but it allows acessing the structured array fields as attributes (i.e., `arr.Matrix` will return a 1000x3x3 array).  It's handy so you can do things like

```
arr.det = [det(a) for a in arr.Matrix]
```

You can also access fields using bracket notation and the name of the field, which works with recarrays or structured arrays.

```
arr['det'] = [det(a) for a in arr['Matrix']]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example, I'll give it a try

Comment: If i do `arr = np.rec.array(np.ones(1000, dtype=d))` that works, and i can access `arr.det` do I need the view at all?

Comment: @user1767754, that's a new way to me, but it works.  I've updated the answer to use np.zeros, using array there was a typo.